# How can use matches(advanced) in looker to filer records last 30 days before the recent Monday

Tags: looker-studio, looker

I'm working on a Looker dashboard, and I need to filter records based on a date dimension for the last 30 days before the most recent Monday. I understand that I can use the matches(advanced) filter in Looker, but I'm unsure how to write the expression for this specific requirement. Could someone provide guidance or an example of how to achieve this using matches(advanced) in Looker? Thank you!

I have tried using
“before Monday for 30 day” but it’s not working. I know “before Monday” returns all records before the most recent Monday, but i wanna limit that to the last 30 days before the most recent Monday.